# How to handle correctly DispatcherTimer / Queue when a ViewModel is not visible

Tags: c#, wpf

In a WPF application with MVVM pattern, I have a DockManager that show different panes, based on customer's configuration.

Some of those View/ViewModel process data from a Queue with a DispatcherTimer that after some time passes and process the queue (this choice has been chosen since data are processed at a really high frequency and binding directly to the DataItems would degrade performances.

Doing some test I've discovered (and this's correct) that the DispacterTimer is called even if the View/ViewModel is not shown and this takes resources on the main thread that's better to perform other stuff then updating useless ViewModel (since the data are updated frequently, so 99% the data that's updated are old when a user pushes the pane in the top)

I was wondering what's the best approach to process those data. At first sign, I thought to skip the update at all and delegate it to a later process (when the view is pushed on top, but this way I would have a lot of work to do before latest data are shown.

Here's the dispatcher's tick event

```
    private void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ScrollViewer != null)
        {
            HorizontalScrollViewOffset = ScrollViewer.HorizontalOffset;
            VerticalScrollViewOffset = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        }

        lock (_queueLock)
        {
            while (queue.Count > 0)
            {
                var deal = queue.Dequeue();

                Serilog.Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Dequeued {deal.Deal.Id} from deal queue");
                if (deal.Status == DealStatus.New && !dealmapping.ContainsKey(deal.Deal.Id))
                {
                    lock (DealLock)
                    {
                        Deals.Add(deal.Deal);
                        dealmapping = Deals.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, y => y);
                    }

                    Serilog.Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Added {deal.Deal.Id} to deals");
                }
                else
                {
                    lock (DealLock)
                    {
                        if (dealmapping.ContainsKey(deal.Deal.Id))
                        {
                            var oldItem = dealmapping[deal.Deal.Id];

                            var index = Deals.FindIndex(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id);
                            //var index = Deals.IndexOf(oldItem);
                            if (index > -1)
                            {
                                if (deal.Status == DealStatus.Updated)
                                {
                                    //Deals[index] = deal.Deal;

                                    Deals[index].PopulateWith(deal.Deal);

                                    Deals[index].IsChanged = true;

                                    Serilog.Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Updated {deal.Deal.Id} inside deals");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Deals.Remove(Deals.First(x => x.Id == deal.Deal.Id));
                                }
                            }

                            lock (DealLock)
                            {
                                dealmapping = Deals.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, y => y);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Serilog.Log.Verbose($"Deal base - Updated lookup table with deal {deal.Deal.Id}");
            }

        }
    }
```

My first idea was to add `if(!IsActive) return` but this won't process the queue, any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably best "Processing" them as they come in.
Partly in case the process gets more complicated but de-coupling sounds like a good plan anyhow.

I think the thing getting the data would more "correctly" be considered to be the model rather than a viewmodel.
I would run it on a background thread, grabbing the data into a list. Probably a circular list if there's a lot. Insert new entries at index 0 and remove any that are at index 100 or 1000 or whatever.
Every 10 or 20 that then messages that its got new data.
I'd probably use mvvmlight messenger but you could use eventaggregator if your project has prism. Or even just a static bridging class as an intermediary.
Bind an attached property from the view to tell the viewmodel whether the view isvisible or not.
The viewmodel gets the "I got news" message.
If it's view isvisible then it re-reads the data from the model.
If it changes from isvisible false to true, it re-reads the data from the model.
You would need to keep the collection size small or how many incoming pieces of data you leave it for high if you need to present a lot of records with a lot of columns.
Bear in mind that records which aren't presented can be virtualised and the main cost of presenting a collection of data is in the view.

If you do need to worry about the size of that list then a more complicated approach might be necessary.
Add the new entries to a queue (as well).
When the viewmodel is instantiated it gets all the data from the model as above.
Otherwise, it gets the message there are new entries.
It reads new ones off a fifo queue and inserts each as item 0 in an observablecollection the view bounds to.
The model could expose that queue or, again, it could be in a static bridging object.

By the way.
With high data throughput, logging each can be a significant overhead.

Comment: So you would remove the dispatcher timer? and also, I agree with you to process on another worker thread (in that way I can also let it go), the problem is that I would have to put a dispatcher.BeginInvoke when updating/adding items

Comment: I'd probably just use async await rather than a dispatcher timer. I'd do the processing on a background thread. Messenger has thread affinity so that'd need to be dispatcher invokeasync'd but you're doing like 10, 20 or whatever of these things and then send one message.  I gather there are actually a number of these going on so maybe this is hundreds or thousands of records processed and then send one message.

Comment: with async/await yo don't have the guarantee that the thread will be the Main (UI) one

Comment: You can either await a task that does all your processing and then return to the UI thread and process the results. OR. You could run the whole thing on a separate thread and just use await task delay like a timer. In which case you'd need to dispatcher invokeasync back to the ui thread.

Answer (score 0):

this is how y manage that...you have to choose where to process data and transform them in ViewModel. only thing is to fill the observable on the dispatcher thread....

### Mainviewmodel

```
_UpdateTimerClock = new DispatcherTimer();
_UpdateTimerClock.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);
_UpdateTimerClock.IsEnabled = true;
_UpdateTimerClock.Tick += UpdateTimerClockElapsed;


public void UpdateTimerClockElapsed(object tag, EventArgs args)
{
    try
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationViewModelRefresh());
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        BusinessLogger.Manage(err);
    }
}
```

### child view model

```
public ViewModel()
{
    try
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationViewModelRefresh>(this, HandleRefreshAction);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        BusinessLogger.Manage(error);
    }
}

private void HandleRefreshAction(NotificationViewModelRefresh msg)
{
    if (!this.IsVisible)
        return;
```

### child view

```
public View()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    {
        this.IsVisibleChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (this.IsVisible)
                (this.DataContext as ViewModel).Refresh();
        };
    }
}
```

### in the refresh or more general process task in your timer ...

```
Task tk = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        if (System.Threading.Monitor.TryEnter(_RefreshLocker))
        {
            try
            {
                VisualHelper.InvokeBackground(() =>
                {
```

### visual helper extract

```
private static void BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority prio, Action action)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Application.Current != null)
            {
                if (Application.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    action();
                else
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(prio, (ThreadStart)(() => action()));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            BusinessLogger.Manage(err);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I like your approach, so in the VisualHelper you perform the update on the DataItems (an ObservableCollection<T>), Btw why do you use a dispatchertimer if you just send a NotificationMessage?

Comment: I use a DispatcherTimer because it is integrated  in the native Dispatcher of WPF. The VisualHelper is a shorcut to manage the IU thread (completed the answer) and yes it is to modify objects and collection related to UI - btw, i do not understand well your code because you do not name your classes with "model" or "viewmodel" sufix...:-)